# Django: where are packages installed

Tags: django

I am quite a django n00b, but I am reading the eyes out of my head to get it all going. I have a PHP background and struggle with the way and location of reusable apps.

I thought that installed apps should go in an App folder (example django-registration or django-profiles), but after I PIP the app in my virtualenv, I see that the app is installed in a Django folder names "site packages".

Is this the default behavior? Should I copy the 'registration' or 'profile' folder from site packages to my Project? or should I leave them there

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

If you're intending to simply install packages and not amend their code, there's no problem with them living in Python's `site-packages` dir.

Because you're using virtualenv, the packages installed while that virtualenv is active will be stored in:

```
/path/to/virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.x/site-packages/
```

And it's completely fine for them to stay there. As Daniel R says, what matters is that they are your PYTHONPATH, and virtualenv takes care of making sure they are.

Custom apps you write go in your project. Installed apps you just want to import from into your custom apps can stay in the site-packages folder.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with Django. This is where Python installs packages. Django doesn't care where they are, as long as they're on the Pythonpath (which they are if they're in site-packages).